# I have installed GDAL library but am having troubles importing and using it. What should I do?

Tags: python-3.6, geospatial, gdal, geopandas

When importing the GDAL package in python, it's raising the following error:

```py
>>> import gdal

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/akki/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "/home/akki/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/akki/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/akki/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/akki/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libpoppler.so.71: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed GDAL foloowing command on my conda virtual environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

Comment: Please format the code properly and add all the relevant information, for others to understand and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

`from osgeo import gdal`

Comment: just write in your environment console
`conda list`
and check if gdal is listed there

Comment: Done that! **GDAL 2.2.2** shows up  `conda-forge`  channel. Also, when you see the error's first line, you find _python3.6/site-packages/gdal.py_. The actual error is import error for **_libpoppler.so.71_**